# matriz espiral en c

Tags: c, algoritmos

Hice un algoritmo para generar una matriz espiral dados la cantidad de fila y columnas, pero no funciona para todas las matrices y no se muy bien cual podria ser el error

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
    unsigned short fila, columna ;
    printf ("Ingresar cantidad de filas: \n");
    scanf("%hd", &fila);
    printf("Ingresar cantidad de columnas: \n");
    scanf("%hd", &columna);
    int matriz[fila][columna];
    void GenerarMatriz (unsigned short, unsigned short, int[][columna]);
    GenerarMatriz(fila,columna, matriz);
    return 0;
}

void GenerarMatriz (unsigned short fila, unsigned short columna, int matriz[][columna])
{
    unsigned short i, j, inicio, limitecolumna, limitefila, tope, x;
    inicio = 0; //desde donde comienza a llenarse
    limitecolumna = columna ;// donde comienza el desenso
    limitefila = fila;
    tope = fila * columna ;//hasta donde se llena, que es la cantidad de elementos
    x = 1; //valores dentro de la matriz
    i = 0 ;
    /*La matriz se llena con 4 for, dos para filas y dos para columnas.
    Los primeros dos for empiezan cargando la primera fila y la ultima      
    columna. Los otros dos cargan cargan desde la ultima fila hacia la 
    ultima columna. Los for no estan anidados, el while debe ejecutarse         
    hasta llenar la matriz*/

    while (x <= tope)
    {
        for(j = inicio; j < limitecolumna  ; j++ )
        {
        matriz[i][j] = x++;
        /*x++;*/
        }
        for(i = inicio + 1 ; i < limitefila  ; i++)
        {
        matriz[i][j-1]= x++;
        /*x++;*/
        }
        for (j = limitecolumna - 1 ; j > inicio ; j--)
        {
        matriz[i-1][j-1]= x++;
        /*x++;*/
        }
        for (i = limitefila - 1; i > inicio + 1 ; i--)
        {
        matriz[i-1][j]= x++;
        /*x++;*/
        }
        inicio++;
        limitecolumna --;
        limitefila--;
    }
    for (i =0 ; i < fila ; i++){
    printf("\n");
    for (j = 0; j < columna ; j++)
    printf("%i\t", matriz[i][j]);
    }
    }
```

por ejemplo para una matriz de 4x5 esta es la impresión, lo cual es correcto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
pero para una de 3x4, este es el resultado 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

gracias desde ya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error se produce en el tercer bucle for, las condiciones que tienes permiten que se actualize el valor de en las coordenadas (1,1) de la matriz, aunque esas coordenadas ya se han actualizado en el primer bucle for, sobrescribiendo el valor en ese elemento.

Una simple solución es añadir una condición extra para el tercer bucle for, que compruebe que no se sobrescribe la fila calculada por el primer bucle for, y que podría quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
for (j = limitecolumna - 1 ; j > inicio && i > inicio + 1; j--)
{
matriz[i-1][j-1]= x++;
/*x++;*/
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo!

Comment: @LuzBenítez si esta respuesta soluciona tu problema no olvides marcarla como solución

Answer (score 0):

```
Esta es una solución que hice hace un tiempo atrás, espero te sirva


#include <stdio.h>
#define N 100
int llenar(int tam,int tam2,int aux, int n, int k,int m);
int Aspiral[N][N];
int main() {
    int tam,n;
    int i,j,k=0,m=0,fin;
    printf("Ingrese el tamaño de el espiral: ");
    scanf("%d",&tam);
    for(i=0;i<tam;i++){
        for(j=0;j<tam;j++){
            Aspiral[i][j]=0;
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
    if(tam % 2 == 0){
        fin = tam/2;
        /*n debe ser par*/
        n=tam-6; /*asignamos el valor de n el cual cambia con el valor de la matriz*/
    }else{
        fin = (tam+1)/2;
        /*n debe ser impar*/
        n=(tam)-6;
    }
    /*printf("%d",fin);*/
    for(i=0;i<fin;i++){
        m = llenar(tam-i,tam,i,n,k,m);/*aux2 y aux lo reemplazamos por i*/
        k=k+2;
    }
    for(i=0;i<tam;i++){
        for(j = 0; j <tam; j++){
            printf(" %d ",Aspiral[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
int llenar(int tam,int tam2,int aux, int n,int k, int m){
    int i,x=1,aux2;
    for(i=aux;i<tam;i++){
        Aspiral[aux][i] = x + m;                                        
        Aspiral[i][(tam-1)] = x + m + 5 -(k*1) + n;                     
        Aspiral[tam-1][(tam-1)-i+(aux)] = x + m + 10 -(k*2) + n*2;  
    
        if(i < (tam-1)){
            Aspiral[(tam2-1)-i][aux] = x + m + 15 -(k*3) + n*3;
            aux2 =  x + m + 15 -(k*3) + n*3;                                                
        }
        x++;
    }
    return aux2;
}
```